# What is the best weapon to fight the Dancer of Boreal Valley?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I have triggered the fight early, and am currently using the Grass Crest Shield, Astora Straight Sword and the Assassin armour set. I feel that the range of my sword is less. After dodging her attack, my sword doesn't reach her.

Which is the best weapon to use against the Dancer of Boreal Valley?

Comment: In current state this question is too broad. What exact problems do you have with dancer? what's your current build?

Comment: I have triggered the fight early . I am using grass crest shield , astora straight sword and assassin armour set. I feel that the range of my sword is less. After dodging her attack , my sword doesn't reach her.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FPELc1wEvk) video has a decent strategy when triggering the Dancer of Boreal early on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really any particular advice on how to handle this boss, especially this early. Even though you have triggered it early, the boss isn't scaled down to match you, so a lot of this fight is going to be about tactics - poke; then run away. Repeat until dead.

At this stage of the game, a lot of the equipment that is available is going to make little difference. Your best bet is honestly Firebombs. They do flat damage, and more than likely more than you'll be able to do with any other weapon you can wield at this stage.

If you want to use them, she is weak to Lightning damage, and you do have access to 3 bolt resin at this stage, so try that if/when you run out of firebombs.

Other than that, just practice not getting hit.